# Maven can't find locally installed archetype

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-archetype

I'm trying to setup a basic spring mvc archetype.

As Spring comes with great samples, it also comes with a basic mvc setup.

So I checked that out:

```
svn https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/
```

Changed the dir name trunk to spring-mvc-basic.

Next I create the ~/.m2/settings.xml (is it normal this file hasn't been created before)
Then I add

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"                                                                                                
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
        <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
        <!--localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository2</localRepository-->
</settings>
```

Then inside the spring-mvc-basic directory I run:

```
mvn install
```

When I look in .m2/repository/org/springframework/samples spring-mvc-basic is created there.

Next I wanted to generate an archetype based on my previous work:

```
mvn archetype:generate --batch-mode -DarchetypeArtifactId=mvc-basic -DgroupId=org.foo.bar -DartifactId=TestMVC -Dversion=0.1-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=org.springframework.samples
```

But this for some reason I can't comprehend the command always fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.springframework.samples:mvc-basic:1.0) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Next I wanted to generate an archetype based on my previous work:

By this, what do you mean?  Do you want to make this work available to others by converting it to an archetype project?  If so, you have chosen the wrong command for this.  You would need to do [mvn archetype:create-from-project](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Edited.

The problem is that the packaging of the project isn't `maven-archetype`, so maven will just install it as a regular war project not an archetype project.
So basically you can't generate a new project from that source, but you can copy the source tree and modify the files you want - thus creating your project.

Or you could:

1. convert the source to a maven archetype and install it
2. use the `appfuse-basic-spring` archetype (from this [list](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List))

Comment: I don't think that's the main issue I'm having. Tried by adding the version param but I'm still getting:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.springframework.samples:mvc-basic:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Updated answer, also consider @raghuram suggestion!